# How to convert array keys to $_POST[name]

Tags: php, arrays, post

If a have a form input with a name like "name[0][firstname]", $_POST will retrieve that as:

```
 'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=9)
          'firstname' => null
```

so `echo $_POST['name'][0]['firstname']` will give me null.

The question is how can I build the post query dynamically from the array keys? so, for example:

```
$foo = array('name', 0, 'firstname'); 
echo $_POST[$foo];  // obviously doesn't work
```

What I need do is build this statement, `$_POST['name'][0]['firstname']`, from the array but can't find a way to do it. I thought maybe `$_POST{'[' . implode('][',$foo) . ']'}` might work but I get Undefined index: `['name'][0]['firstname']`.

Final solution **

With regards to the solution by @Alireza and @Matteo, both work, except in the case if the array is longer than the $_POST array, eg, if array is $foo = array('name', 0, 'firstname', 'lastname') and the post value is array['name'][0]['firstname'] = "XXX" the result will be "X" which is index 0 of the result XXX. Therefore it needs to check the keys of the post and not the value.

The final solution for me is therefore:

```
function getValue($res, $foo)
{
    foreach ($foo as $val) {
        if (is_array($res) && array_key_exists($val, $res)) {
            $res = $res[$val];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Examples:

```
$post = array(
  'name' => array(
    0 => array(
      'firstname' => 'XXX'
    ),
  )
);

echo getValue($post, array('name', 0, 'firstname'));
> XXX    
echo getValue($post, array('name', 0, 'firstname', 'lastname'));
> false
echo getValue($post, array('name', 0, 'firstname', 0));
> false
echo getValue($post, array('name', 0, 0));
> false  
echo getValue($post, array('name', 0));
> Array (eg, Array ( [firstname] => XXX )) - expected
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try var_dump( $_POST ); to see what you're getting.

Comment: `echo $_POST[$foo[0]][$foo[1]][$foo[2]];` maybe?

Comment: Bit vague & crazy. But `$_POST[$foo[0]][$foo[1]][$foo[2]];` is that what you want ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Alireza answered the question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is **very** easier :

```
$foo = array('name', 0, 'firstname')
$res = $_POST;
foreach ($foo as $val) {
    $res = $res[$val];
}
echo $res;
```

### Example :

```
$array[0]['f']['p'][8]['Hi'] = 'Hello World!';
$foo = array(0,'f','p',8,'Hi');
$res = $array;
foreach ($foo as $val) {
    $res = $res[$val];
}
echo $res;
```

Echoes `'Hello World!'`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out if it works for your use:

```
function getArrayValue($basearray,$name){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $argc = func_num_args();
    $base = isset($basearray[$name])
        ? $basearray[$name]
        : null;
    if($argc > 2 && is_array($base)){
        for($i=2; $i < $argc; $i++){
            $base = getArrayValue($base,$args[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $base;
}

$myname = getArrayValue($_POST,0,'firstname');
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there should be only one closing parenthesis in the following line:

```
$foo = array('name', 0, 'firstname');
```

Secondly, you need a recursive function if you would like to create a multidimensional array using the values of `$foo` as keys:

```
function create_multidimensional_array(&$arr, $keys, $val){
    if($keys === array()){
    $arr = $val;
    }
    else{
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    $arr[$key] = array();
    create_multidimensional_array($arr[$key], $keys, $val);
    }
}

$foo = array('name', 0, 'firstname');
create_multidimensional_array($_POST, $foo, "Charles");
print_r($_POST);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Charles
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getValue($array, $key) {
    $val = NULL;

    foreach((array) $key as $k) {
        $val = @$array[$k];
        $array = @$array[$k];
    }

    return $val;
}
```

So if for example

```
$array = array(
  'name' => array(
    0 => array(
      'firstname' => 'XXX'
    ),
  )
);
```

then `getValue($array, 'name') == array(0 => array('firstname' => 'XXX'))` and `getValue($array, array('name', 0, 'firstname')) == 'XXX'`

For a live example, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0780e1165ee9851f33fb1e019717ab32cd527d51

Comment: Thank @Matteo, that works but I needed to create a post statement

Comment: What does that mean? My function works perfectly using `$_POST` as the array: `getValue($_POST, array('name', 0, 'firstname'));`

Comment: Actually that only works for finding a value of a key in an array but I was more after something like getValue($_POST, 'name[0]['firstname'])) which would ultimately result in $val = $_POST['name'][0]['firstname'].

Comment: The point is I need to dynamically create the post variable from an array. In my script i have the name of the field stored as 'name[0]['firstname'] which is easily to convert to ['name'][0]['firstname']. I just did not know how to combine it with $_POST to make $var = $_POST['name'][0]['firstname'];

Comment: I still do not understand, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: yes you are quite right, your solution does work perfectly. I preferred the accepted answer as it was more succinct....